# Why adding an extra previous setup breaks upgrade path in InstallShield?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, patch

I'm creating a patch for my product. This is the third patch for the base version. My upgrade paths are as follow:

- 1.0   -->1.0.3
- 1.0.1 -->1.0.3
- 1.0.2 -->1.0.3

What I did was to create a new patch in Patch View and set 1.0.3 as the latest version and 1.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 as the previous versions. (I followed the same approach when created the patches 1.0.1 and 1.0.2)

The problem I have is that the upgrade path from 1.0 to 1.0.3 is NOT working, but only if I add 1.0.2 to the previous versions list. If I remove 1.0.2 from the previous versions, the 1.0-->1.0.3 upgrade path works perfectly.

Does anybody know what could be wrong in this scenario?

Note: I have seen this issue in both InstallShield 12 and InstallShield 2011.

Note 2: Could someone please tag this as InstallShield-2011 and InstallShield-12, the tags don't exist and I cannot create them because don't have enough points. Thanks.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Juan C. Becerra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some [component rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa372795) may be broken in the 1.0.2 installer.  To find out where the problem may lie, I'd recommend running the Upgrade Validation Wizard, which you can get to from the menu by clicking **Build | Validate | Upgrade Validation Wizard...**

Here, you can specify your most current setup, and specify the paths to the previous ones, and then it will check to see if there could be any problems that may result in a failed upgrade scenario.

Best of luck,

Bryan

Comment: Hi Bryan. It seems like you are right. I haven't tried the Upgrade Validation Wizard, but I will. What I did was to try my patch with a newer version of one of the main files and it is working fine now. It seems like the old file that I used during the development was breaking the rules and causing the upgrade to fail. Just as a note: the file was a non-versioned executable. Thank you very much for your answer.